# Python Tkinter Treeview - How do I determine if the last child is displayed?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have created a treeview that displays incoming messages.  As the number of messages received exceeds the size of the treeview window, I use this line of code
`self.logTree.yview_moveto(1)`
to make sure the latest message is always displayed at the bottom of the window.  However, I want to stop this behavior if the user scrolls up.  I need a means for determining whether the last received message is displayed.  How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bbox()` to check whether an item of `Treeview` is visible:

```
# get the iid of last item
last = tree.get_children()[-1]
# bbox() returns the bounding box of the item if it is visible
# otherwise it returns empty string
visible = tree.bbox(last) != ""
```

Comment: Perfect!  This solves my problem.  Thanks